# Get audio from HTML5 video

Tags: javascript, html, api, audio, video

I have been trying to figure out this for a week.
I have two completely different video tags with their respective audio. I also have one audio tag. At first, both muted attribute is set for both video tags. When I want to get video1 audio, I would like to get it audio source and assign it to the audio tag. Also do the same for video2.

Is this possible with Javascript? I have tried Web audio API but I'm lost. Please help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am not sure I get what you want.

To copy the video's audio stream to an audio element, you could simply set the src of the `<audio>` element to the video's src  :

```html
<audio src="http://media.w3.org/2010/05/sintel/trailer.mp4" controls autoplay></audio>
```

Then you could try to sync it with your video tag's `currentTime`, or sync the video's `currentTime` with the `<audio>`'s one and unmute the video, while the audio would be muted, but I'm not sure you'll get awesome results. Also, it won't be a surprise if some browsers will load the video twice in the same time.

---

**Now, what can you do with the WebAudioAPI :**

It would be really hard to make your audio streams into the audio tags, live and in a cross-browser way.

If you don't need this however, it's pretty easy to create some MediaSource from video elements thanks to the [`createMediaElementSource()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioContext/createMediaElementSource) method.

Once these MediaSource objects are created, your original media will be disconnected from the normal output. **You need to keep their `muted` attribute unset or set to false** in order to hear it as a MediaSource object.

Here is a simple example that will allow you to mute/unmute a video source, from the WebAudioAPI only :

```js
var vid = document.getElementById('vid');

var audioCtx = new AudioContext();
var gainNode = audioCtx.createGain();
var v1_src = audioCtx.createMediaElementSource(vid);

gainNode.connect(audioCtx.destination);

btn_1.onclick = function() {
  var playing = this.textContent.indexOf('listen') < 0;
  if (playing) {
    v1_src.disconnect();
    this.textContent = this.textContent.replace('mute', 'listen');
  } else {
    v1_src.connect(gainNode);
    this.textContent = this.textContent.replace('listen', 'mute');
  }
}
```

```css
video {  height: 120px;}
```

```html
<button id="btn_1">listen</button><br>
<video id="vid" crossOrigin='anonymous' src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/v/oceans.mp4" loop autoplay></video>
```

Note that the media passed to this method must come from a safe domain request (see [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS)).

Comment: Hi. Thanks, this is just want I need.