# Extracting audio from a video file

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api

**Edit**: [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34984501/get-audio-from-html5-video) is no duplicate of mine. I am trying to extract the audio data as binary, got no problems with playing the audio file as separate as I mentioned before.

I am trying to extract audio from a video file on client-side by using [Web Audio Api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Audio_API).

```
var audioContext = new(window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)();
fileData = new Blob([input.files[0]]);
var videoFileAsBuffer = new Promise(getBuffer);
videoFileAsBuffer.then(function (data) {
    audioContext.decodeAudioData(data).then(function (decodedAudioData) {
        mySoundBuffer = decodedAudioData;
        soundSource = audioContext.createBufferSource();
        soundSource.buffer = mySoundBuffer;
        // soundSource.connect(audioContext.destination);
        // soundSource.start();
    });
```

When I uncomment the two lines at the end, I am hearing the sound of the uploaded video file. Though, when I create a link to download the file with the help of `getChannelData` method, it's almost the same size as video file.

I was expecting `decodedAudioData` to have only audio binary data, and send that to my webservice, which is the only one I need. However, that didn't work out as I expected. Anyone knows a way to extract audio of a video file on client-side? Thanks in advance.

Here is the `getBuffer` method in case anyone wants to know:

```
function getBuffer(resolve) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function () {
        var arrayBuffer = reader.result;
        resolve(arrayBuffer);
    }
    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(fileData);
}
```

**Edit**: I was able to decode the video file and get audiobuffer by using [OfflineAudioContext](https://developer.mozilla.org/tr/docs/Web/API/OfflineAudioContext) inside *decodeAudioData* function.

```
var offlineAudioContext = new OfflineAudioContext(2, 44100 * 100, 44100);
var soundSource = offlineAudioContext.createBufferSource();
...
soundSource.connect(offlineAudioContext.destination);
soundSource.start();
offlineAudioContext.startRendering().then(function (renderedBuffer) {
    console.log(renderedBuffer); // outputs audiobuffer
    var song = audioContext.createBufferSource();
    song.buffer = renderedBuffer;
    song.connect(audioContext.destination);
    song.start();
}).catch(function (err) {
    console.log('Rendering failed: ' + err);
});
```

`renderedBuffer` is an audiobuffer, had no problem outputting the data, tested with [Audacity](https://www.audacityteam.org/)'s import raw data option. But the problem is, the new file (filled with `renderedBuffer.getChannelData(0)`) has higher size than the original video has. Isn't that supposed to have lower size since it only contains audio of the video file?

Comment: Looks like there's a rather simple avenue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34984501/get-audio-from-html5-video

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get audio from HTML5 video](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34984501/get-audio-from-html5-video)

Comment: @jmcgriz In that post there is no such thing related to extracting binary audio data from video **file** as I asked for. It just crops the audio data from the video **element** and **plays it** with the help of _createMediaElementSource_ method.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, I actually had the answer already. Raw audio data is huge, that's why it's even greater than the video itself in size.

```
var offlineAudioContext = new OfflineAudioContext(numberOfChannels, sampleRate * duration, sampleRate);
var soundSource = offlineAudioContext.createBufferSource();
...
reader.readAsArrayBuffer(blob); // video file
reader.onload = function () {
  var videoFileAsBuffer = reader.result; // arraybuffer
  audioContext.decodeAudioData(videoFileAsBuffer).then(function (decodedAudioData) {
    myBuffer = decodedAudioData;
    soundSource.buffer = myBuffer;
    soundSource.connect(offlineAudioContext.destination);
    soundSource.start();

    offlineAudioContext.startRendering().then(function (renderedBuffer) {
      console.log(renderedBuffer); // outputs audiobuffer
    }).catch(function (err) {
      console.log('Rendering failed: ' + err);
    });
  });
};
```

After that, I was able to convert the audiobuffer *(renderedbuffer)* into a wav file by using [audiobuffer-to-wav](https://github.com/Jam3/audiobuffer-to-wav) library. OfflineAudioContext is just needed to modify the cropped audio.

**Edit:**
Here is the [js fiddle example.](https://jsfiddle.net/8w5xs9o5/23/) **decodedAudioData** method will suffice if you don't want to override the audio data.

Comment: Could you please provide a full example, like with all the code all put together? A JSFiddle would work as well.

Comment: @SamuelWilliams Actually, this is the full example already. You just need to get the video file e.g. for getting it as input `var file = document.getElementById('file').files[0];`

Comment: @SamuelWilliams Check out the [js fiddle example.](https://jsfiddle.net/8w5xs9o5/23/)

Comment: Thank you. Turns out iOS Safari doesn't like `OfflineAudioContent.startRendering()` for some reason. It just never finishes rendering. I'll look into it.

Comment: Ok well I guess I'm not gonna be able to convert video to WAV on iOS Safari. (At least until the [bug](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=181939) is fixed.)

[Here's my version that works everywhere else.](https://jsfiddle.net/ayunami2000/c5xdL6xL/)

Comment: How to do this if I am having video url only and not the file locally on my system?

Answer (score 2):

I'm using this code to extract audio:

```
// initialize the audioContext
var audioContext = new webkitAudioContext();
var video = document.getElementById("myVideo");
var mediaSource = audioContext.createMediaElementSource(video);
var analyser = audioContext.createAnalyser();
mediaSource.connect(analyser);
analyser.connect(audioContext.destination);
```

---

```
// this will give you the sound data

video.play();

function getSoundData() {
   var sample = new Float32Array(analyser.frequencyBinCount);
   return analyser.getFloatFrequencyData(sample);  
}
```

**EDIT:**

I've not run this code so far but I think this should work also:

Fetching an `XMLHttpRequest` to your **videourl** (working also with local files) instead of using WebAudio API.

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', 'https://test.com/myvideo.mp4', true);
xhr.responseType = 'blob';

xhr.onload = function(e) {
    var binaryData = this.response;
    console.log(binaryData)
};

xhr.send();
```

**EDIT 2:**

```js
var audioFileUrl = 'video.mp3';

fetch(audioFileUrl)
  .then(function(res) {
    res.blob().then(function(blob) {
      var size = blob.size;
      var type = blob.type;

      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.addEventListener("loadend", function() {

        var base64FileData = reader.result.toString();

        var mediaFile = {
          fileUrl: audioFileUrl,
          size: blob.size,
          type: blob.type,
          src: base64FileData
        };

      });

      reader.readAsDataURL(blob);

    });
  });
```

or try using some kind of code like this:

```
<audio id="audio" src="http://yourvideo.com/video.mp4" controls autoplay></audio>


function getAudio() {
  var elem = document.getElementById("audio")

  // get Base 64 string from elem.src
}
```

I hope it is helpful because for me these few lines are working quite fine so far `:)`

Comment: Hmm, I've also checked this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17531692/how-can-audio-be-extracted-from-a-video-in-html5), but couldn't work it out. Does this mean I have to run the video 'till the end?

Comment: In this case, using the code above: **YES**. You have to use some interval to get the SoundData for the current position and you can write this into an array or object! @starkm

Comment: So, let's say if the video is at 2 hours at length, will user have to wait around 2 hours to extract the audio from the video file to save from upload size? Or do we have a fast-forward like method? A real world example would be awesome.

Comment: In this case (using AWI, yeah). Have a look at to different suggestions in my updated answer! @starkm

Answer (score 0):

I think you should change your code from

```
var soundSource = offlineAudioContext.createBufferSource();
......
soundSource.connect(offlineAudioContext.destination);
```

to these

```
 const soundSource = audioContext.createBufferSource()
 soundSource.buffer = decodedAudioData
 soundSource.connect(audioContext.destination)
```

in order to play the audio

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/OfflineAudioContext for reference